# Change the input field referencing Select Drop-down Value in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the following coding,

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model,'guesstype',array(''=>'--select--','logo'=>'Logo','apaters'=>'Apaters','text'=>'Text'),array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>255)); ?>
```

When i am choosing logo means, the input field becomes fileFieldRow,

```
<?php echo $form->fileFieldRow($model,'logo',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>255)); ?>
```

When i am choosing text means, the input field becomes textFieldRow,

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'name',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>255)); ?>
```

How to change input field based upon selected value in select list. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, but i think you have to do something like this with jQuery,

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('helloscript',"
   $(document).on('change', '#id-of-dropdown', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == dropdown_value_that_you_want_to_match) {
        $('#id-of-element').show();
    } else {
        $('#id-of-element').hide();
    }
});
",CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

?>